Using Automator to connect to SMB shares
I’m trying to write an Automator Workflow to reconnect macOS to some not-very-remote SMB shares (on a server beside the Mac). For some reason adding them to my login items doesn’t always work.
Using an old answer at:
How can I get Automator to mount a network volume?
I have two actions:

Get Specified Servers, where I list the shares
Connect to Servers

The problem is that if the share is already mounted, I get a “Connect to Servers failed” error, and the script exits without trying the next one.
Is there a way to test for the server first, or at least to ignore the error?

Seems like it would be easier to just Applescript it.  Here is the one I use.  Obviously server and share names would have to be changed, as well as the protocol if the server doesn’t support AFP.
tell application "Finder"
    try
        mount volume "afp://DiskStation.local/Archive"
        mount volume "afp://DiskStation.local/Documents"
        mount volume "afp://DiskStation.local/Media"
        mount volume "afp://DiskStation.local/Pictures"
    on error number n
        display alert ("Error " & n & " on network share mount")
    end try
end tell

